# If I create vectors using new and place them in a vector, will the outer vector or inner vector desctructor delete them?

Tags: c++, std, new-operator, stdvector, delete-operator

Having a lot of problems putting `vector`s into `vector`s (`vector<vector<string>>`), I has to new the inner vectors and `push_back(*pointer)`.  Will the outer `vector` `erase()` `delete` them?  I tried an explicit `delete` and got more errors.  How does one manage creating objects to put into container classes (by reference) that are not identical local objects but do not need to be tracked for `delete`?

Comment: What's the reason for creating vectors using `new`?  Why not simply use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about C++ here.

When you put raw pointers into a `vector`, the `vector` will not delete them when it's destroyed. If you want to have the `vector` delete the pointers, you need to use a smart pointer, like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` (do not use `auto_ptr`).

However when it comes to `vector`s, it rarely makes sense to allocate them on the heap. Since the introduction of move semantics in C++11 there isn't really any reason not to just stick a `vector` inside another `vector`. So if you want to nest `vector`s, just go with `vector<vector<int>>`, not `vector<vector<int>*>` or `vector<unique_ptr<vector<int>>>`.

Comment: c++ is my first tag.  I said push_back(*pointer), where *pointer is a dereference of a pointer from "new vector<string>;", so what about my question?  How would you create containers on the heap, of containers on the heap, of containers on the heap, simply?

Comment: If you must put them on the heap (and it won’t make much difference if you do, other than to make your life more difficult, since vector already places its internal data on the heap anyway), then use a smart-pointer class (as suggested in this answer) to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: C++ is in the list of tags because I added it. Regarding heap-allocated containers, I agree with Jeremy: it just doesn't make sense, because vector is internally basically just a triple of a pointer and two `size_t`s. The actual data already sits on the heap, so putting another pointer in between will only make things slower and messier.

Comment: A colleague suggested I delete them right after I push them back into the parent vector, and that seems to work, so does vector copy push_back inputs?  If so, why do I have problems if I feed it a local vector?  Avoiding a copy seems so difficult and yet copy reliant code seems to blow up many ways!  (At least in C I knew what was happening!  std class descriptions are often very terse!)

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett Your colleague needs to tell you *why* whatever he suggested "works".  To me, the suggestion sounds like a hack that just moves the corruption bug somewhere else in your program.  My suggestion is to make the code simply use value-semantics -- no pointers.  Then when you reproduce the error, actually fix the error, not mask it by making changes you (or probably your colleague) has no idea why it works.

Comment: `push_back` will either copy or move its inputs into the vector, where “copy” means invoking the object's copy constructor. For a pointer, said copy constructor it will only copy the pointer, not the data it points to, so if you pass a pointer to `push_back` and then `delete` it, you're going to have an invalid pointer in your vector and bad things will happen if you ever dereference it.
Long story short: messing around with raw pointers , `new` and `delete` is almost always a stupid idea. Use containers, use smart pointers.

Comment: So when does it move not copy?  When you pass a &&?  It feels like the & and && enhancements and many std behaviors were invented to keep incompetent programmers form fumbling their pointers into segv or leaks so often.  Lots of gratuitous copying and cloning going on, with loss of throughput compared to making something, using it and passing it by reference!  Does one of these smart pointers call destructors and then delete when appropriate?

Comment: You do realize that having to ask that question makes you the incompetent one around here, don't you?

`push_back` will move if you pass it an rvalue. This is *not* the same as passing an expression with a `&&` type, and a complete explanation won't fit here. You can start reading up on rvalue references and move semantics here:
http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

Your questions about pointers are based on false premises like “gratuitous copying” and “loss of throughput”, and hence not useful to answer.

Comment: I suppose if I create an && non-const variable and pass it then push_back will move, else it will copy.  It's nice that it passes by reference so objects are not being copied into the stack, but later there is a move or copy.  Personally, for speed, I would rather store pointers than move or copy.  If I get lazy and let it copy local object or locally referenced objects, I hope to not be buried in weird compiler or run time errors, like a wiped stack or complaints from alloc, free().  (Of course if you store pointers, it will copy the pointer, but that is not the copy we are talking about.)

Comment: shared_ptr and unique_ptr feel very JAVA-like!  Are they low overhead?  What if the 'object' is not from a class but a primitive or array of primitives?  Is there a smart pointer that knows to delete it without trying for a destructor?

Comment: Wrong, if you create a variable of `&&` type and pass it to `push_back`, it will *not* move but copy. Again if you want to understand this, you need to read up on how rvalue references and move semantics work.

Comment: That was my first thought, but you said it sometimes moved, and I could not see how, unless the late compile of templated classes let the compiler intervene and convert the & to an &&.  Obviously, making a call to consume an && would step on the very object you wanted to pass unless the compiler stepped in in a big way!

Comment: I've linked to suitable documentation regarding move semantics and rvalue references earlier. Read it.